# How to change Linux kernel name

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

How to change Linux kernel name.

```
uname -s
```

show "Linux", how to set "MYOS"?

I downloaded the source code for the Linux Kernel, but can not find where to change the kernel name and version. Help plz..

Comment: http://goterminal.blogspot.com.es/2012/02/make-kernel-name-same-as-your-name_07.html

Comment: @OscarLT In this article, he added -tveak to version, and I have to completely change the kernel name, and version. Such as MYOS  1.0

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136959/where-does-uname-get-its-information-from

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the UTS_SYSNAME definition, under

> linux-x.xx.xx/include/linux/uts.h

and compile it, then **uname** will return whatever it was set to.

```
#define UTS_SYSNAME "Linux"
```